# Unable to add attributes from the controller in angular js ionic

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs. I am trying to search and navigate to the user on click.On search, I am creating html from the angularjs controller and display in the view.

But the strange thing is, in html I can add attribute class, but not id or ng-click. I just want to add ng-click in the html so that I can perform action on click too. On click I want to navigate to the particular user profile.

Here is my Code, Please review it and suggest me where I am wrong.

```
    .controller('searchDesignCtrl', function($scope,$http,api_root) {
    $scope.html = '<div class="button-bar"><a class="search-item"><i class="ion-person"></i>Username</a><a class="search-item"><i class="ion-person"></i>Username</a><a class="search-item"><i class="ion-person"></i>Username</a><a class="search-item"><i class="ion-person"></i>Username</a><a class="search-item"><i class="ion-person"></i>Username</a><a class="search-item"><i class="ion-person"></i>Username</a></div>'
    $scope.searchuser = function(element){
        $scope.value_input = $(element.currentTarget).val();
        var link = api_root+'users/search_users';
        $http({
            url: link,
            method: "POST",
            data: 'uname=' + $scope.value_input,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.fetched_users = data.data;
                $scope.html ='<div class="button-bar">';
                $.each($scope.fetched_users, function(key,value){
                    //here ng-click is not added in the view
                    $scope.html+= '<a class="search-item '+value.User.id+'" ng-click="navigate_to_user()"><i class="ion-person"></i>'+value.User.username+'</a>'; 
                });
                $scope.html +='</div>';
//                console.log($scope.html);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});
    }
    $scope.navigate_to_user=function(){
        console.log($scope);
    }
})
```

Comment: Angularjs goes through compilation in order to add its built-in directives like ng-click. To add these after the dom has been rendered, you need to use the $compile service provided by Angular. [this article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx) explains it pretty well. And there are also the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex for answer. 
Using the $comiple service provided by the angular, I am able to fix this. Here is the documention: [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

In my case to view the html, I wrote compile directive:

```
.directive('compile', function($compile) {
      // directive factory creates a link function
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(
          function(scope) {
             // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
          },
          function(value) {
            // when the 'compile' expression changes
            // assign it into the current DOM
            element.html(value);

            // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
            // scope.
            // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
            // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          }
        );
```

and in view I just wrote:

```
<div compile="html"></div>     //uses the $compile directive
```